# Without using webdriver add-in how to execute the SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver used excel macro

Tags: excel, selenium, vba

I have created an excel vba macro code using selenium webdriver.

"Dim selenium As New SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver".

It works well in my system as I have used "SeleniumWrapperSetup-1.0.17.0" to create the macro. But I cannot ask my whole team to install SeleniumWrapperSetup-1.0.17.0 as business wont accept installing the same in all my team members systems(around 200).

Is there a way where I can execute the selenium based macro(Helps to fetch data from the webpage in Chrome browser) without installing the seleniumWrapper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter what flavor of Selenium you use, you will have to at least distribute some files. If it helps people get the job done more quickly, why wouldn't the business support this?

Have you considered writing the tool in C#, compiling it into an EXE, and the distributing it with the Selenium dlls? It will avoid installation but you will still have to distribute files.

Another option is to write the script in Selenium IDE and distribute the script. Everyone would have to install the Selenium IDE (Firefox browser plugin).

If your team members are somewhat web savvy, you could write the scraper in Javascript and give them a file that they could run as a Chrome snippet in their browser... no installs necessary.